# Algorithm optimization in PHP app

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization

I'm working on a web application project which displays a list of results to the customer, with pictures, description and some other info. I want to optimize the routine responsible for displaying the results.

Let's say that we have a total of 200 results (products). For each one of them a function is called (let's call it DisplayResults), that fetches some pictures, description, and some other stuff.

DisplayResults currently is within a foreach loop, so as I already mentioned, for each one of the results we have a new function call.

I'd like to ask: how can I optimize this sequence? If I fetch all the info needed to display with a function OUTSIDE the foreach loop (for all the results at once), will I see some difference?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: I'm already using pagination. The data have been already fetched from the database and are stored in an array, so no need for SQL optimization at this point, in my opinion...

EDIT #2: This is how foreach-loop looks like:

```
foreach ($total['product_data'] as $product_data) {
   $tags['$$searchProductList'] .= DisplayResults($product_data);
}
```

And this is how DisplayResults looks like:

```
function DisplayResults ($data) {
  $tags['$$Description'] = substr($data['description'],0,70)." ...";
  $tags['$$FeaturesList'] = getFeatures($data['features']);
  $tags['$$PhotosList'] = getPhotos($data['photos']);
  $tags['$$Offers'] = getOffers($data['offers']);
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The $data variable contains all the information fetched from the DB for the current result.

Comment: Assuming the data comes from a database, learn how to use JOINs in SQL queries

Comment: How could we tell? We don't have the faintest idea of what your function does or how it accomplishes it.

Comment: In order to get helpful answers, you should add some more info about how you fetch the additional information. Furthermore I think you should consider some pagination - 200 results on one page seems a little too much.

Comment: Show us the database structure and SQL code, that fetches the products

Comment: @Sirko Consider about 20 results in each page for a total of ten pages.

Comment: So what do getFeatures(), getPhotos() and getOffers() all do?

Comment: @Mark Baker Nothing special. Mostly, echoing HTML depending on the input.

Comment: Unless you're doing something terribly wrong (such us calling `trim()` 20,000,000 times for each string you print) the performance gain you can obtain by simply reducing the number of function calls is most likely tiny compared to the usual application bottlenecks. You have the means and the information: you know how you app works, you can run a profiler, you can test stuff. There's no way we can provide useful answers having no info at all.